# Plugin development : from ExpressionEngine to Craft

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Coming to Craft after years with EE, I feel like a newbie again.

I painfully managed to built and install a basic plugin for craft3 with composer, (with a little help from the docs and [NYstudio107's tutorial](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin)).

For now, the plugin does nothing, and to keep going, I would need to understand how to translate a pattern commonly used in EE.
Get some data from a template, process it and return it.

Get tag data and parameters

```
$data_to_process = ee()->TMPL->tagdata;
$process_param = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('parameter');
```

Output content to template

```
ee()->return_data = $processed_data;
```

Ho do you do such things in craft ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a template in Craft 3 you can do

```
$html = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('path/to/template', $variables);
```

If you want to return/render a template within your Controller action you can do

```
return $this->renderTemplate('path/to/template', $variables);
```

If you want to render a plugin template you'll need to attach your plugins handle to your path

```
 'plugin-handle/path/to/template'
```